# Upgrade from 14.04.05 to 16.04.05

Tags: upgrade

I wish to upgrade from 14.04.5 to 16.04.5 (not 16.04.6), what is the best to do this ensuring that I don't upgrade to version 16.04.6?

thanks,

Liam.

Comment: If you were able to upgrade to .5 and do an `apt-get upgrade` you are on .6 so whats the point?

Comment: A particular application that I need to run (at this point in time) is only supported by the vendor if the version of Ubuntu is 16.04.5

Comment: I would check with the vendor and it's likely 16.04.5 was the latest when they updated their site, and they haven't updated their site to allow for 16.04.6. Upgrades now will go to the latest so you can't use automatic tools. You could install 16.04.5 (offline) and then specifically upgrade to the packages you want - but it'll be a lot more manual work (putting holds on them so they won't upgrade anymore), but automatic tools auto-upgrade to the latest so you can't use automatic tools.

Comment: 18.04.5 was released officially 2018-Aug-02 (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2018/08/02/ubuntu-16-04-5-lts-released/) and 18.04.6 on 2019-Feb-28 (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2019/03/01/ubuntu-16-04-6-lts-released/) though installed systems get it before release date (which signifies  ISO release).  As in last comment, I suspect they just haven't updated their site since 2019-Feb, and it's unwise to go to 16.04.5 unless machine is offline; OR work out packages & just mark 'hold' those required deps as with my prior comment  (you didn't say if server or desktop, I've done it for desktops as outlined)

Comment: I would like the vendor to use 18.04.x but they have insisted that they will only support 16.04.5 - maybe this is what they have tested and documented and feel comfortable supporting this - they will not give me an answer as to why .6 would not be supported. I thought by manually editing sources.list e.g with a manual entry could force the update to be 16.04.5 and not 16.04.6.